# Sum numbers if date is same

Tags: python, date, sum

I am looking for a way to sum the second columns by the date.

For example, `20220606 -28.29 20220606 8.0`   should be: `20220606 -20.29`

So at the end I will get 1 date of each one with the total sum.

Thanks!

```
20220316 -1425.66
20220606 -28.29
20220606 8.0
20220606 10.0
20220324 74.86
20220324 48.58
20220210 428.22
20221004 1328.9
20211227 -23.64
20211227 -22.54
20211227 -23.14
20211227 -120.71
20211227 -243.26
20211217 -19.95
20211217 -112.95
20211217 -19.03
20211217 -202.43
20211217 -22.68
20211221 24.37
20220228 -69.31
20220228 57.24
20220228 13.48
20220228 14.48
20220228 13.98
```

Comment: NIce question. So what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

**Just taken the first 10 values of your data and used a dictionary to store the `key`{date} and his `sum`{value}.**
You can apply on your full data.

**Code:-**

```
lis=[[20220316, -1425.66],
    [20220606, -28.29],
    [20220606, 8.0],
    [20220606, 10.0],
    [20220324, 74.86],
    [20220324, 48.58],
    [20220210, 428.22],
    [20221004, 1328.9],
    [20211227, -23.64],
    [20211227, -22.54],
    [20211227, -23.14]]
dic={}
for i in lis:
    dic[i[0]]=dic.get(i[0],0)+i[1]
print(dic)
```

**Output:-**

```
{20220316: -1425.66, 20220606: -10.29, 20220324: 123.44, 20220210: 428.22, 20221004: 1328.9, 20211227: -69.32}
```

Comment: thanks. how do I make the 2 dimensional list? I get each column alone.

Comment: got it 'lis.append([x,x])'

Comment: Yes you are right this will work `lis.append([x,x])`